# Error in starting the Kubernetes minikube cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have Kubernetes v1.10.0 and minikube v0.28 installed in MacOS 10.13.5. But while starting the minikube, I am getting constant errors:

$ minikube start

```
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Starting cluster components...
E0708 16:13:43.193267   13864 start.go:294] Error starting cluster:  timed out waiting to unmark master: getting node minikube: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/nodes/minikube: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: i/o timeout
```

i have also tried $minikube start and $minikube delete as well as reinstallation of minikubes versions but that didn’t help.

```
$ minikube version
minikube version: v0.28.0

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.0", GitCommit:"91e7b4fd31fcd3d5f436da26c980becec37ceefe", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-27T20:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: i/o timeout
```

Even I am not able to ping the virtual machine . But I can see the minikube VM in my virtualBox in Running status.

Minikube Logs:

```
    F0708 16:46:10.394098    2651 server.go:233] failed to run Kubelet: unable to load bootstrap kubeconfig: stat /etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf: no such file or directory
Jul 08 16:46:10 minikube systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jul 08 16:46:10 minikube systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: Flag --cadvisor-port has been deprecated, The default will change to 0 (disabled) in 1.12, and the cadvisor port will be removed entirely in 1.13
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: Flag --cgroup-driver has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: Flag --allow-privileged has been deprecated, will be removed in a future version
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: Flag --cluster-domain has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: Flag --client-ca-file has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: Flag --fail-swap-on has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: Flag --pod-manifest-path has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: Flag --cluster-dns has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: Flag --authorization-mode has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.694078    2730 feature_gate.go:226] feature gates: &{{} map[]}
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: W0708 16:46:20.702932    2730 hostport_manager.go:68] The binary conntrack is not installed, this can cause failures in network connection cleanup.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.703121    2730 server.go:376] Version: v1.10.0
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.703187    2730 feature_gate.go:226] feature gates: &{{} map[]}
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.703285    2730 plugins.go:89] No cloud provider specified.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.726584    2730 server.go:613] --cgroups-per-qos enabled, but --cgroup-root was not specified.  defaulting to /
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.726934    2730 container_manager_linux.go:242] container manager verified user specified cgroup-root exists: /
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.726983    2730 container_manager_linux.go:247] Creating Container Manager object based on Node Config: {RuntimeCgroupsName: SystemCgroupsName: KubeletCgroupsName: ContainerRuntime:docker CgroupsPerQOS:true CgroupRoot:/ CgroupDriver:cgroupfs KubeletRootDir:/var/lib/kubelet ProtectKernelDefaults:false NodeAllocatableConfig:{KubeReservedCgroupName: SystemReservedCgroupName: EnforceNodeAllocatable:map[pods:{}] KubeReserved:map[] SystemReserved:map[] HardEvictionThresholds:[{Signal:memory.available Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:100Mi Percentage:0} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>} {Signal:nodefs.available Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:<nil> Percentage:0.1} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>} {Signal:nodefs.inodesFree Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:<nil> Percentage:0.05} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>} {Signal:imagefs.available Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:<nil> Percentage:0.15} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>}]} ExperimentalQOSReserved:map[] ExperimentalCPUManagerPolicy:none ExperimentalCPUManagerReconcilePeriod:10s ExperimentalPodPidsLimit:-1 EnforceCPULimits:true}
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.728063    2730 container_manager_linux.go:266] Creating device plugin manager: true
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.728189    2730 state_mem.go:36] [cpumanager] initializing new in-memory state store
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.728313    2730 state_file.go:82] [cpumanager] state file: created new state file "/var/lib/kubelet/cpu_manager_state"
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.728418    2730 kubelet.go:272] Adding pod path: /etc/kubernetes/manifests
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.728460    2730 kubelet.go:297] Watching apiserver
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:20.734450    2730 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:451: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:20.734566    2730 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:460: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dminikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:20.735067    2730 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dminikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: W0708 16:46:20.735453    2730 kubelet_network.go:139] Hairpin mode set to "promiscuous-bridge" but kubenet is not enabled, falling back to "hairpin-veth"
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.735561    2730 kubelet.go:556] Hairpin mode set to "hairpin-veth"
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.744020    2730 client.go:75] Connecting to docker on unix:///var/run/docker.sock
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.744065    2730 client.go:104] Start docker client with request timeout=2m0s
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: W0708 16:46:20.750158    2730 hostport_manager.go:68] The binary conntrack is not installed, this can cause failures in network connection cleanup.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.752473    2730 docker_service.go:244] Docker cri networking managed by kubernetes.io/no-op
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.756618    2730 docker_service.go:249] Docker Info: &{ID:K2FS:LJJY:RYGP:JKVS:74G5:3HA4:L26I:VOFW:CGF5:JB6F:BMQV:G3GO Containers:0 ContainersRunning:0 ContainersPaused:0 ContainersStopped:0 Images:0 Driver:overlay2 DriverStatus:[[Backing Filesystem extfs] [Supports d_type true] [Native Overlay Diff true]] SystemStatus:[] Plugins:{Volume:[local] Network:[bridge host macvlan null overlay] Authorization:[] Log:[awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog]} MemoryLimit:true SwapLimit:true KernelMemory:true CPUCfsPeriod:true CPUCfsQuota:true CPUShares:true CPUSet:true IPv4Forwarding:true BridgeNfIptables:true BridgeNfIP6tables:true Debug:false NFd:23 OomKillDisable:true NGoroutines:35 SystemTime:2018-07-08T16:46:20.753639901Z LoggingDriver:json-file CgroupDriver:cgroupfs NEventsListener:0 KernelVersion:4.16.14 OperatingSystem:Buildroot 2018.05 OSType:linux Architecture:x86_64 IndexServerAddress:https://index.docker.io/v1/ RegistryConfig:0xc420122fc0 NCPU:2 MemTotal:2088189952 GenericResources:[] DockerRootDir:/var/lib/docker HTTPProxy: HTTPSProxy: NoProxy: Name:minikube Labels:[provider=virtualbox] ExperimentalBuild:false ServerVersion:17.12.1-ce ClusterStore: ClusterAdvertise: Runtimes:map[runc:{Path:docker-runc Args:[]}] DefaultRuntime:runc Swarm:{NodeID: NodeAddr: LocalNodeState:inactive ControlAvailable:false Error: RemoteManagers:[] Nodes:0 Managers:0 Cluster:<nil>} LiveRestoreEnabled:false Isolation: InitBinary:docker-init ContainerdCommit:{ID:9b55aab90508bd389d7654c4baf173a981477d55 Expected:9b55aab90508bd389d7654c4baf173a981477d55} RuncCommit:{ID:9f9c96235cc97674e935002fc3d78361b696a69e Expected:9f9c96235cc97674e935002fc3d78361b696a69e} InitCommit:{ID:N/A Expected:} SecurityOptions:[name=seccomp,profile=default]}
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.756704    2730 docker_service.go:262] Setting cgroupDriver to cgroupfs
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.768856    2730 remote_runtime.go:43] Connecting to runtime service unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.772344    2730 kuberuntime_manager.go:186] Container runtime docker initialized, version: 17.12.1-ce, apiVersion: 1.35.0
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: W0708 16:46:20.772666    2730 probe.go:215] Flexvolume plugin directory at /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec/ does not exist. Recreating.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.772949    2730 csi_plugin.go:61] kubernetes.io/csi: plugin initializing...
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:20.821518    2730 kubelet.go:1277] Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data for container /
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.822056    2730 fs_resource_analyzer.go:66] Starting FS ResourceAnalyzer
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.822138    2730 status_manager.go:140] Starting to sync pod status with apiserver
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.822179    2730 kubelet.go:1777] Starting kubelet main sync loop.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.822215    2730 kubelet.go:1794] skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime is down PLEG is not healthy: pleg was last seen active 2562047h47m16.854775807s ago; threshold is 3m0s]
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.822420    2730 server.go:129] Starting to listen on 0.0.0.0:10250
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.822963    2730 server.go:299] Adding debug handlers to kubelet server.
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.823936    2730 volume_manager.go:247] Starting Kubelet Volume Manager
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:20.824420    2730 event.go:209] Unable to write event: 'Post https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/default/events: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused' (may retry after sleeping)
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.825365    2730 server.go:944] Started kubelet
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.825492    2730 desired_state_of_world_populator.go:129] Desired state populator starts to run
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.922627    2730 kubelet.go:1794] skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime is down]
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.924838    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:271] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:20.927054    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:82] Attempting to register node minikube
Jul 08 16:46:20 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:20.927586    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:106] Unable to register node "minikube" with API server: Post https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:21 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:21.123837    2730 kubelet.go:1794] skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime is down]
Jul 08 16:46:21 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:21.127937    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:271] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Jul 08 16:46:21 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:21.130362    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:82] Attempting to register node minikube
Jul 08 16:46:21 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:21.130766    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:106] Unable to register node "minikube" with API server: Post https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:21 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:21.524092    2730 kubelet.go:1794] skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime is down]
Jul 08 16:46:21 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:21.531377    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:271] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Jul 08 16:46:21 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:21.534027    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:82] Attempting to register node minikube
Jul 08 16:46:21 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:21.534443    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:106] Unable to register node "minikube" with API server: Post https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:21 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:21.736215    2730 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:451: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:21 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:21.741184    2730 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:460: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dminikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:21 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:21.742867    2730 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dminikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:22 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:22.324217    2730 kubelet.go:1794] skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime is down]
Jul 08 16:46:22 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:22.334948    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:271] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Jul 08 16:46:22 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:22.337989    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:82] Attempting to register node minikube
Jul 08 16:46:22 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:22.338431    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:106] Unable to register node "minikube" with API server: Post https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:22 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:22.737509    2730 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:451: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:22 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:22.741882    2730 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:460: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dminikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:22 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:22.743575    2730 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dminikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:22 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:22.908788    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:271] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Jul 08 16:46:22 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:22.910882    2730 cpu_manager.go:155] [cpumanager] starting with none policy
Jul 08 16:46:22 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:22.910923    2730 cpu_manager.go:156] [cpumanager] reconciling every 10s
Jul 08 16:46:22 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:22.910931    2730 policy_none.go:42] [cpumanager] none policy: Start
Jul 08 16:46:22 minikube kubelet[2730]: Starting Device Plugin manager
Jul 08 16:46:22 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:22.922215    2730 eviction_manager.go:246] eviction manager: failed to get get summary stats: failed to get node info: node "minikube" not found
Jul 08 16:46:23 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:23.739107    2730 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:451: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:23 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:23.742661    2730 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:460: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dminikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:23 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:23.744902    2730 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dminikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:23 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:23.925063    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:271] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Jul 08 16:46:23 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:23.936151    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:271] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Jul 08 16:46:23 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:23.936545    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:271] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Jul 08 16:46:23 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:23.938910    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:271] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Jul 08 16:46:23 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:23.946028    2730 reconciler.go:207] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "kubeconfig" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/host-path/099f1c2b79126109140a1f77e211df00-kubeconfig") pod "kube-scheduler-minikube" (UID: "099f1c2b79126109140a1f77e211df00")
Jul 08 16:46:23 minikube kubelet[2730]: W0708 16:46:23.946195    2730 status_manager.go:461] Failed to get status for pod "kube-scheduler-minikube_kube-system(099f1c2b79126109140a1f77e211df00)": Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-scheduler-minikube: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:23 minikube kubelet[2730]: I0708 16:46:23.946773    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:82] Attempting to register node minikube
Jul 08 16:46:23 minikube kubelet[2730]: E0708 16:46:23.947106    2730 kubelet_node_status.go:106] Unable to register node "minikube" with API server: Post https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 08 16:46:23 minikube kubelet[2730]:
```

Comment: hi, I have minikube version: v0.27.0 running on sieera, and didn't experience any problems...did you try reinstalling virtualbox?

Comment: ok i will try to reinstalling virtualBox . Few week before it was working fine

Answer (score 0):

Its working as expected, earlier I was facing connectivity problem from host to vm , that time I was using hotspot internet connection. That might be the issue to connect my vm .

Now on Home wifi the minikube delete and minikube start works perfectly .

Thanks